# the right expression for ["A" for x in range(0,10) or "B" if x == 9] in python?

Tags: python, list-comprehension, shortcut

I want to express `x is in range(0,10), if x == 9 then "B", else "A"`, what is the right expression for that with in a line? Thanks!

```
["A" for x in range(0,10) if x == 9 or "B"]    # wrong
["A" for x in range(0,10) or "B" if x == 9]    # wrong
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
["A" if x == 9 else "B" for x in range(0,10)]
```

Comment: ah, I see, thanks! but should be `["B" if x == 9 else "A" for x in range(0,10)]`, right?

Comment: It depends what you want. Include in your question what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively:

```
>>> ['A']*9+['B']
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option:

```
>>> d = {9:"B"}
>>> [d.get(n, "A") for n in range(10)]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B']
```

This is a bit more useful if you have several `B` values to insert.

Answer (score 0):

['B' if x==9 else 'A' for x in range (0,10)]